# Count the number of possible results via JavaScript and Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a filter with multiple options. As you can see, there are sometimes no results. I give this back to the visitor as user feedback by saying: no results.

Now I want to show the visitor the number of results already in the filter option. For example: Show all (10) or Education (1). This way a user knows what he can expect and don't choose for a emptyenter code here filter.

But something makes it really complex: The numbers can change with certain combination. For example: if you choose filter one, there are less options for filter two. etc.

Can anyone help me?

Already tried to make use of the 'length' property but it didn't work or I didn't use it the right way.

```
$("select.filterby option").each(function() {
    var t=$(this),
        val=t.val(),
        text=t.text(),
        count=$("#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card."+val).length;
    v.text(text+" ("+val+")");
});
```

```
$("select.filterby").change(function() {
  var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e) {
    return $(e).val();
  }).join(".");
  $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card").hide();
  if ($("div#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card." + filters).length) {
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.job-offer-card." + filters).show();

  } else {
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.noresults").show();
  }
});


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span> View by:</span>


    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select id="location" class="filterby">
       <option value="all">Show All</option>
       <option value="australia">Australia</option>
       <option value="singapore">Singapore</option>
       <option value="newzealand">New Zealand</option>
       <option value="usa">USA</option>
       <option value="uk">UK</option>
       <option value="vietnam">Vietnam</option>
       <option value="global">Global</option>
       <option value="othercountry">Other</option>
    </select>


    <label for="type">Type</label>
    <select id="type" class="filterby">
       <option value="all">Show All</option>
       <option value="accommodation">Accommodation</option>
       <option value="app">App/Technology</option>
       <option value="business">Business</option>
       <option value="health">Health</option>
       <option value="hospitality">Hospitality</option>
       <option value="education">Education</option>
       <option value="retail">Retail</option>
       <option value="services">Services</option>
       <option value="travel">Travel</option>
    </select>

    <label for="code">Code</label>
    <select id="code" class="filterby">
       <option value="all">Show All</option>
       <option value="001">001</option>
       <option value="002">002</option>
       <option value="003">003</option>
       <option value="004">004</option>
    </select>

<div id="FilterContainer">
  <div class="job-offer-card noresults">
    <p>no results</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel 004">
    <p>1 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam  travel 003">
    <p>2 all vietnam travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>3 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia accommodation travel 003">
    <p>4 all australia accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia education">
    <p>5 all australia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam newzealand usa accommodation">
    <p>6 all vietnam accommodation</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>7 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam  travel">
    <p>8 all vietnam travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation travel">
    <p>9 all vietnam accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia accommodation travel">
    <p>10 all australia accommodation travel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all australia health 001">
    <p>11 all australia</p>
  </div>
  <div class="job-offer-card all vietnam accommodation 002">
    <p>12 all vietnam accommodation</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't working because you aren't taking the current value of the other two selects into account when creating your count selector.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. How do I overcome this?

Comment: You would probably need to update the options text every time a select value changes. That means being able to differentiate the selects and use the values of the other 2 in addition to the value of the option you are updating. Not sure if this is clear ?